# Accidentally removed app from Genymotion. Not syncing with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

I accidentally uninstalled the apk file from Genymotion. Now, the debug option in android studio cannot make the app work on Genymotion. How to make things correct again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call adb kill-server and adb start-server. Now Run the app again. 
If this doesn't work then close genymotion and start again.